# WebGL troubleshooting

Tags: webgl, ubuntu-12.10, tilt

I am using ubuntu 12.10 OS. I would like to learn WebGL programming.

All at a sudden my WebGL stopped working. Initially firefox provided 3d way of looking at webpage elements. But now it's not working. Saying "Could not initialize Tilt, please check the
troubleshooting information available at http://get.webgl.org/troubleshooting" in an alert box.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Ddi you check weither webGL was enabled in about:config?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, in my case while webgl.disabled=false, webgl.force-enabled=true helped.